# Searching Active Directory using Sid

Tags: c#, active-directory

Can I get a User object using user's SID ?

Does samaccountname is unique for every user in active directory ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bind to an object directly given its SID like this:

```
var entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://<SID=S-your-sid-here>");
```

Both SID and sAMAccountName are unique in the domain.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a really old post, but I'll elaborate on the answer: The SID is always unique, and does not get repeated over time. SAMAccountNames are also unique in the present time. Once "smiths" gets deleted, another "smiths" can then be created. Whereas a SID will not be repeated. The slight difference in context can matter depending on timings involved.